# В чем причина (java.io.IOException: No such file or directory)?

Tags: java, android, файлы, path, filestream

Пытаюсь записать аудио-поток в файл на устройство. 
 Права на чтение/запись файлов в манифесте присутствуют.

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

При нажатии по соответствующей кнопке в активити, к которой привязан слушатель, в котором должен сработать метод,  я получаю исключение следующего рода:

```
   03-21 23:11:53.066 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at com.pro.utils.AudioRecorder.createFile(AudioRecorder.java:226)
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at com.pro.utils.AudioRecorder.<init>(AudioRecorder.java:188)
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at com.pro.ui.activity.StationActivity$5.onClick(StationActivity.java:287)
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6199)
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23647)
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    03-21 23:11:53.067 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    03-21 23:11:53.068 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    03-21 23:11:53.068 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
    03-21 23:11:53.068 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyFirstApp/DFMDeep_20180321111153.mp3 (No such file or directory)
    03-21 23:11:53.068 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    03-21 23:11:53.068 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    03-21 23:11:53.068 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
    03-21 23:11:53.069 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at com.tequila.online.radio.pro.utils.AudioRecorder.<init>(AudioRecorder.java:191)
    03-21 23:11:53.069 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at com.tequila.online.radio.pro.ui.activity.StationActivity$5.onClick(StationActivity.java:287)
    03-21 23:11:53.069 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6199)
    03-21 23:11:53.069 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23647)
    03-21 23:11:53.069 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    03-21 23:11:53.069 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    03-21 23:11:53.069 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    03-21 23:11:53.069 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    03-21 23:11:53.069 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    03-21 23:11:53.069 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    03-21 23:11:53.069 13790-13790/com.pro W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
    03-21 23:11:53.070 13790-13790/com.pro I/System.out: [http://uplink.181.fm:8026/;] : true
```

подаю url-адрес потока в метод в активити (StationActivity):

```
button_rec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (Streamer.getInstance().isPlaying()) {
            StationActivity.isRecording = true;
            AudioRecorder audioRecorder = new AudioRecorder(Streamer.getInstance().getStation().getStreams().toString(), StationActivity.context);
            button_rec.setImageResource(R.drawable.admin);
            System.out.println(Streamer.getInstance().getStation().getStreams().toString() + " : " + isRecording);
        } else if (StationActivity.isRecording && Streamer.getInstance().isPlaying()) {
            StationActivity.isRecording = false;
            button_rec.setImageResource(R.drawable.aboutus_menu);
            System.out.println(Streamer.getInstance().getStation().getStreams().toString() + " : " + isRecording);
        }
    }
});
```

собственно сам класс, на который всё подаётся:

```
  public class AudioRecorder {

private Context context;
MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder = null;

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class AudioStreamRecordTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, FileOutputStream> {
    private FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

    private AudioStreamRecordTask() {
    }

    protected FileOutputStream doInBackground(Object... params) {
        URL url;
        MalformedURLException e;
        FileNotFoundException e2;
        IOException e3;
        this.fileOutputStream = (FileOutputStream) params[0];
        try {
            URL url2 = new URL(Streamer.getInstance().getStation().getStreams().toString());
            try {
                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url2.openStream());
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while (true) {
                    int i;
                    int bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer);
                    if (bytesRead > 0) {
                        i = 1;
                    } else {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    if ((i & ExoPlayer.STATE_READY) == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    this.fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                this.fileOutputStream.flush();
                this.fileOutputStream.close();
                url = url2;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e4) {
                e = e4;
                url = url2;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e5) {
                e2 = e5;
                url = url2;
            } catch (IOException e6) {
                e3 = e6;
                url = url2;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e7) {
            e = e7;
            e.printStackTrace();
            return this.fileOutputStream;
        }
        return this.fileOutputStream;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    }
}

public static class Transliterator {
    private Map<Character, String> charMap = null;

    public Transliterator() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.charMap = new HashMap();
        this.charMap.put(Character.valueOf('\u0410'), "A");
        ...
        this.charMap.put(Character.valueOf(' '), "_");
    }

    public String transliterate(String string) {
        StringBuilder transliteratedString = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            Character ch = Character.valueOf(string.charAt(i));
            String charFromMap = this.charMap.get(ch);
            if (charFromMap == null) {
                transliteratedString.append(ch);
            } else {
                transliteratedString.append(charFromMap);
            }
        }
        return transliteratedString.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
}

public AudioRecorder(String stream_url, Context context) {
    FileNotFoundException e;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    IOException e2;
    this.context = context;
    File stream_file = createFile();
    if (stream_file != null) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream2 = new FileOutputStream(stream_file);
            new AudioStreamRecordTask().execute(fileOutputStream2, stream_url);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e5) {
            e = e5;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private File createFile() {
    File newSoundFile;
    Date dNow = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss", Locale.getDefault());
    //Парсим название станции
    String filename = Streamer.getInstance().getStation().getName();
    filename = (filename + "_" + ft.format(dNow) + ".mp3").replaceAll("\\s", "");
    File path;
    String path2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "MyFirstApp/";
    if (isSDPresent()) {
        path = new File(path2);
        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdirs();
        }
        newSoundFile = new File(path, filename);
    } else {
        path = new File(path2);
        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdirs();
        }
        newSoundFile = new File(path, filename);
    }
    if (newSoundFile.exists()) {
        newSoundFile.delete();
    }
    try {
        newSoundFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newSoundFile;
}

private String generateFileName(String name) {
    return "";
}

private static boolean isSDPresent() {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals("mounted");
}

public static String getFileDuration(String filePath, Context context) {
    long duration = 0;
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp.reset();
        if (isSDPresent()) {
            mp.setDataSource(filePath);
        } else {
            mp.setDataSource(new FileInputStream(filePath).getFD());
        }
        mp.prepare();
        duration = (long) mp.getDuration();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }
    String out = "";
    String seconds = String.valueOf((duration % 60000) / 1000);
    String minutes = String.valueOf(duration / 60000);
    if (seconds.length() == 1) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    if (minutes.length() == 1) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    return String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + seconds;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема была в разрешениях. Нужно не просто запрашивать в манифесте, но и самому запросить разрешение перед созданием файла/папки. Установил запрос на кнопку, которая соб-нно и начинает запускать метод (запись потока).

```
  //динамическое получение прав на WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Permission is granted");

  //что то делаем

} else {
         android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
         //запрашиваем разрешение
         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StationActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас файл /storage/emulated/0/MyFirstApp/DFMDeep_20180321111153.mp3 не существует.
Возможно, произошла ошибка при создании файла, которую вы благополучно заглушили этим кодом:

```
try {
    newSoundFile.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

ИМХО, так лучше не делать, а чтобы проверить что за ошибка была, псмотрите вывод консоли, или пробрасывайте IOException выше.

Comment: проблема была в разрешениях. Нужно не просто запрашивать в манифесте, но и самому запросить разрешение перед созданием файла/папки. Установил запрос на кнопку, которая соб-нно и начинает запускать метод . Вопрос только в том, как остановить запись? что отвечает за сохранение файла при остановке записи? Просто я когда запускаю метод, вроде запись потока идёт, но остановить её не могу. соответственно созданные файлы в папке имеют вес 0 байт.

Comment: @Антон, запомните раз и навсегда: потоки должны быть закрыты (`close()`) в любом случае(записан, прочитан, не нужен, произошла ошибка, наступил конец света...). Реальная запись данных на диск происходит после вызова `flush()` или `close()`, который в свою очередь вызывает `flush()`.